# How to iterate List<Map> in java?

Tags: java, list, collections, maps

I want to iteate List and If that key is "Happy" then I want to store that in a variable.

Eg:- `List<Map> list=service.getValues();`

Comment: please share your effort in solving this?

Comment: And what exactly is the problem you are having? You can iterate over it like you would iterate over any collection.

Comment: And you didn't find any idea about that already ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first of all **DONT USE RAW** Types

after that, do an enhance **for loop** to iterate the list, every element is a map, then get the entrySet of that

```
List<Map<String, String>> list = ...;
        for (final Map<String, String> element : list) {
            for (final Entry<String, String> entryElem : element.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("Key: " + entryElem.getKey());
                System.out.println("Value: " + entryElem.getValue());
            }
        }
```

---

## java8

the nested for loops can be resumed to:

```
list.forEach(element-> element.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println));
```

Answer (score 0):

I just traversed the list. Getting the map then travesring the map.

```
String output="";
            List<Map<String,String>> list=new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
            {
                Map<String,String> map=list.get(i);
                Set<String> set=map.keySet();
                Iterator it=set.iterator();
                while(it.hasNext())
                {
                    String key=(String) it.next();
                    if(key.equals("Happy"))
                        output=map.get(key);
                }
            }
```

Comment: You're still using a raw `Iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String var=null;
    List<Map> list=new ArrayList<Map>(0);
    for(Map map:list){
    for(Object key:map.keySet()){
    String obj=key.toString(); 
    if(obj.equals("Happy"))
    {
      var=key;
      System.out.println(var);
    }
    }
}
```

1. Create a List object
2. Iterate through it using enhanced for loop.
3. Store the key one by one in a object(or else you will get Type mismatch error)
4. convert the object into string
   5.finally match your string with "Happy"
5. if matches, Stroe it in variable and return successfully.

Comment: Also consider removing the usage of raw types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Answer (score -1):

```
List<Map> list = service.getValues();    

for(Map map : list) {
    for(String key : map.keySet()) {
        if(key.equals("Happy")) {
           //do something with key
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String

Comment: where u type case this..

Comment: `Map<String,Object>` because for now, this is like `Map<Object, Object>`

Comment: Ofcourse, my code is generic. I have no idea how your Map looks like. What type are the Keys? What type are the values?

Please tell me

Comment: JavaBoy, don't write "code only" answers. Explain your answer.

Comment: @Tom I see you run around stackoverflow and act like the comment-police? Please contribute by helping people, instead of generating comments. Thanks.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14851671)

Comment: @bsiamionau A code-only answer might not be a good one, but it's still an answer. I would recommend you this post about the LQPRQ: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Comment: @FelixSFD this code is not valid, it doesn't provide an answer

Comment: @bsiamionau That's an issue on StackOverflow, even a broken/incomplete answer is considered an answer and therefore not eligible to be flagged as either VLQ or NAA.

Comment: @Tom That's not a problem. We have downvotes to show, that an answer is incorrect or not useful.

Comment: @FelixSFD That *is* a problem, as it pollutes the site with bad/incomplete/wrong answers/question which remains here. This site was supposed to be a collection of question of all kinds (in the scope of this site) with quality answers. One can still vote about the quality of *working* answers, but something that doesn't work shouldn't be tolerated.